# How to add button and a processing layout on android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, processing

I'm a student in 2 year electrical and computer science : i am not familiar with android studio (most of the time i work on C++).

I made a joystick on processing for an android project, and then I exported my processing sketch to android studio, now I have to find a way to recover data (vector position) from my processing sketch to my main activity.

BUT here is the problem:

- I want to add a TextView to my main activity but the processing sketch takes all the window, and I can't reduce it.

so what did i try :

- I tried to place the fragment in a relative layout, and then place the TextView but it didn't work, even if i make the fragment very little it still taking the whole screen.

My thought are that there is a problem with this line ->

```
setContentView(frame, new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                                                     ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
```

I made some screenshots:

Here the Main Activity :

```
 @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    FrameLayout frame = new FrameLayout(this);
    frame.setId(CompatUtils.getUniqueViewId());
    setContentView(frame, new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                                                     ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
   // setContentView(R.layout.main); // attach the view for this activity

    sketch = new Joystick();

    PFragment fragment = new PFragment(sketch);
    fragment.setView(frame, this);
  }
```

Here the view of the main activity
[image]

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code. Please post a [mcve] directly in your question.

Comment: why you are not use xml ?

Answer (score 0):

In order to have a fragment in your Main Activity you can do the following:

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);

            SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

            // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.*/
            ViewPager mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
            mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

            TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
            tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);
        }

        /**
         * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
         * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
         */
         private class YourFragmentAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

              SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
              super(fm);
         }

         @Override
         public Fragment getItem(int position) {
             switch (position) {
                 case 0:
                     return new YourFragment()
                 default:
                     return null;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 1;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    return "Your fragment name";
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

    }
```

main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Your fragment class:

```
public class YourFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

In this way you could have an activity with as many views as you want, and as many fragments as you wish. Note that if you have more than one fragment your activity will be more like a tabbed activity.

Comment: Hey ! Thanks ! I will try this today or tomorrow !